# setup.py hangs during cleanup in chroot

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setup.py

I'm having an issue with running setup.py/pip in a chroot environment.

Here's the scoop:

Normal directory location:

```
/local/my_dir/project/src/qa/libs
```

Chroot-ed location

```
/src/qa/libs
```

Here's my setup.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

from __future__ import (unicode_literals, print_function, division,
                    absolute_import)

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

test = [
    'mock',
    'pytest',
    'pytest-cov',
]

setup(
    name='libs',
    version=0.1,
    description='Some desc',
    long_description=open('README').read(),
    author='insert_author_here',
    author_email='insert_email_here',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={},
    include_package_data=True,
    tests_require=test,
    install_requires=[],
    keywords=['qa', 'framework'],
    extras_require={
        'test': test,
    }
)
```

When running `python setup.py develop` in the `libs` directory everything goes swimmingly during the install until the very end.

```
Installed /src/qa/libs
Processing dependencies for libs==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for libs==0.1  # <-- It hangs here
```

This doesn't happen when I'm not currently in chroot (required for the environment) and it seems like setuptools/distribute is getting stuck in a recursive filesystem looking for things to clean up.  Any idea how to fix this?

Installing a requirements.txt file with pip doesn't have any problems like this, so I think it might be the structure of the setup.py file.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the hang occurred during during the bash script that created the virtualenv and installed this package.  I figured this out by executing the script with the `bash -x my_script` command, which showed the actual executing command when the hang occurred.

The setup.py file correctly installs the package and exits successfully.